# Does a Maven packaging type `docker` exists?

Tags: maven, docker

I am trying to figure out how to build Docker images as part of the Maven build process. Basically, I want to create a Maven project which builds a Docker image. I think this makes sense.

But what should the packaging type look like? It's obviously not `jar`, `war` or `maven-plugin`. I tried with `docker` but that does not exist.

Should I just go for `pom` or is there a way to configure custom package types?

Having it at `pom` feels *wrong* to me, as we are producing an output - a Docker image - which is usually not the case in regular `pom` types (parent pom, bom, ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow that's ambitious! When you say you want to build a docker image using Maven, I'm assuming you won't be using `docker build` or other docker commands to generate the final image. Docker images are TAR files so you can use the [Maven Assembly plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/) to generate the desired tar-file image.

In this case, your project's "type" would be "pom" so that the project itself generates a POM file containing the information about how it was built (such as name and version number). The Assembly plugin will also generate and attach the corresponding TAR file so that when you use `mvn deploy` or other commands which reference the package, the associated TAR file will be included.

If you are using docker commands to build the images then you are probably going to have to write a custom Maven extension -- depending on what you want to happen when you run `mvn deploy`. It really depends on your ultimate goal but if you are using this within the confines of Docker then you might do better with a plugin like [dockerfile-maven](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven) which will allow your build to drive the docker workflow of `docker build` and/or `docker push`.

Comment: I did not know the existence of `dockerfile-maven`. Great project, that is what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

Of today, there's a Maven docker plugin that enables `<packaging>docker</packaging>`, here:

https://github.com/fabric8io/docker-maven-plugin

Doc here:

https://dmp.fabric8.io/

But take care to specify `<extensions>true</extensions>`!

Answer (score 0):

Spotify has created a [dockerfile-maven-plugin](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven) that allows you to build and publish Docker images with maven. There is an [example](https://github.com/spotify/dockerfile-maven#example) and lots of other useful info on the project page.